# Why is the syntax for the min and max value of a vector like this in C++?

Tags: c++, syntax

Why do we have to include the asterisk ("*")?
Syntax:

```
*min_element (first_index, last_index);
*max_element (first_index, last_index);
```

Comment: Because `min_element` and `max_element` return an iterator, not the element itself. As for why, not totally sure. Easier to generalize in a way that `min_element` of an empty range returns something meaningful, perhaps.

Comment: @NathanPierson because other tools like `erase` use iterators.

Comment: Excellent point

Comment: Not including the asterisk results in an equally valid statement. What makes you believe the asterisk is necessary? What goes wrong if you don't use it? Maybe you stripped out too much context and removed whatever it is that causes the asterisk to be required?

Comment: By returning the iterator, you have the option to also find out *where* the maximum was, as well as *what* it was (by applying the `*` operator).  If they returned only the value, you'd have the *what* but have no way to retrieve the *where*.

Answer (score 3):

Try to understand in this way:

- `min_element` and `max_element` return an **iterator** i.e a
  **pointer** or we can say an address(memory location) and in that address is our dezired element (min or max whatever we called for)
- So to access a value at an address we have to use '*' (talking
  specifically about c++)
- You can't just print the iterator because it is not defined to have a
  value Eg `cout<<min_element(a.begin(), a.end())`. This is not defined. Although you can use it using a trick
- See the follwing code to gain clearity (here we'll not  :

```
 vector<int> a = { 1, 45, 54, 71, 76, 12 };

    cout << "\nMin Element = "
         << min_element(a.begin(), a.end())-a.begin();
  
    cout << "\nMax Element = "
         << max_element(a.begin(), a.end())-a.begin();
```

O/P :
[image]

As you can see the iterator printed the location of the min and the max element

Comment: Note that using `-` will not work for other containers that do not have random access iterators.  Use `std::distance(a.begin(), std::min_element(a.begin(), a.end()));` instead.